# Extracting bibliography from a PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, extract, bibliography

I'm trying to see if it is possible to extract from a pdf file the bibliography (if it exists) contained in it (maybe in a .bib file format). I saw programs like [mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com)  or [cb2Bib](http://www.molspaces.com/d_cb2bib-overview.php), but it seems to me that they only extract the bibliographical reference of the article itself but not the references contained in the article. 
PS: If I'm off-topic, please forgive me and maybe address me to he correct topic.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1815/34848

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Thanks for your warning. Before writing this post I read it but: 
1- It is a closed post
2- The answers, if I understand well, are not satisfying, in the sense that they answer to the question: how to find bibliographic data OF a pdf article, and not how to extract bibliographic data INSIDE a pdf

Comment: Use `attachfile` to attach the bib to the pdf. Everything else will be OCR.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer: what is `attachfile`? How can I use it, given a pdf file?